# how to use another column instead of ID in FOS UserBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, fosuserbundle

I have a standard instalation of FOS UserBundle and I'm trying to use it on an existing user table. the auto_increment field is called "user_id" instead of "id", and of course I can't change it. 
what can I do to use user_id in this module? I'm not using yml but just the annotations in user class.
cheers